Question regarding questions on this stack exchange that have christian cross over
I'm mostly active on Christianity SE, and I've seen some posts about "What does (insert Islamic understanding here) have to do with (Insert Bible Verse here)?" questions from time to time. They invariably get closed on our SE site as they are not on topic nor could most of our users really answer them.
Would such a question get closed and deleted here? Or is that on topic for this site? I'm asking so I can perhaps direct the person to post their question here and get a real answer, instead of us just closing them when they pop up.

The Stack Exchange model is built around focused expertise; you can go to Islam.SE if you're looking for experts in Islam, and you can go to Christianity.SE if you're looking for experts in Christianity.
While this is normally a strength it can also be a weakness, and your situation is a good example of this: Most questions of this ilk require someone with expertise in both, someone with a firm knowledge of Islamic beliefs but who is also well-versed in the Christian Bible.
Even if you got an answer from someone with those overlapping skillsets, community voting will obviously be biased toward the Islamic and/or Christian understanding (depending on which site it was posted on), and may not accurately reflect the accuracy of the entire answer. As such, it would often be difficult if not impossible to distinguish whether the out-of-scope part of any such answer is right or wrong, fact or opinion, or useful in any way.
This isn't to say that such questions have no place here, but it does mean that it's far too easy for everything to devolve into opinionated argument and debate which is definitely off-topic here, or as a vector for straight-up misinformation which is against the Code of Conduct anywhere. The questionasker needs to be extra careful to ensure that the question is focused on the Islamic perspective of things.

This sounds like the answer I was expecting. As I believe the person asking the question is seeking the islamic understanding I'll try to send them over here. Thanks
